# Angular 2+: How to instantiate a class with data from backend?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a Customer class and a ICustomer interface.

```
interface ICustomer { <-- retrieved from backend
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string; 
    // many more members
}

class Customer { <-- used throughout Angular app
    // other fields
    constructor(public data: ICustomer) {};
    // other methods
    refresh() {
        // ... retrieve customer data from backend
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate Customer with an object like {'id': 5} and invoke its 'refresh()' method. But I get a compile time error, because {'id': 5} does not implement ICustomer.

To solve this I could modify ICustomer with '?'s after every member like :

```
interface ICustomer {
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    address?: string; 
    // many more members
}
```

Now {'id': 5} is (technically) an instance of ICustomer.

But that feels wrong. Is there a better solution to this ?

Edit: I'm fine with holding the data from backend in a 'data' field of type ICustomer. My question is about instantiation of the Customer class.

Comment: Where is code that creates error?

Comment: VS Code, the IDE complains. But it's not exactly about the error, but rather the approach feels wrong. That's why I'm asking if there's a more appropriate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `{'id': 5} as ICustomer`

Should work.